# Validation control using regex? Enter Only alphanumeric atleast one number and char is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have created a regex validation in asp.net. 
Mine requirement is this.

first numeric,

second alphabet,

third only special characters,

fourth alphanumeric atleast onenumber and chars

but the fourth textbox is not working for me. can anyone fix it for me

Aspx page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Validation.aspx.cs" Inherits="ValidatorExample.Validation" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:TextBox ID="textBox1" runat="server" OnTextChanged="textBox1_Validating"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Text="Label" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <br />

        <asp:TextBox ID="textBox2" runat="server" OnTextChanged="textBox1_Validating"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Text="Label" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />

        <asp:TextBox ID="textBox3" runat="server" OnTextChanged="textBox1_Validating"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Text="Label" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <br />

        <asp:TextBox ID="textBox4" runat="server" OnTextChanged="textBox1_Validating"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Text="Label" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        <br />

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

aspx.cs

 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

 {

            Regex regex = new Regex(@"[^0-9]");

            Regex reg = new Regex(@"[^a-zA-Z]");

            Regex reg1 = new Regex(@"[^a-zA-Z0-9]");

            Regex reg2 = new Regex(@"^[0-9a-zA-Z*]+$");


            Label1.Visible = false;
            Label2.Visible = false;
            Label3.Visible = false;
            Label4.Visible = false;

            if (regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text))
            {
                Label1.Text = "Enter Only numbers";
                Label1.Visible = true;
            }
            if (reg.IsMatch(textBox2.Text))
            {
                Label2.Text = "Enter Only alphabets";
                Label2.Visible = true;
            }

            if (reg1.IsMatch(textBox3.Text))
            {
                Label3.Text = "Enter Only alphanumeric";
                Label3.Visible = true;
            }
            if (reg2.IsMatch(textBox4.Text))
            {
                Label4.Text = "Enter Only alphanumeric atleast onenumber and char";
                Label4.Visible = true;
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want in the fourth expression. Do you want the string to start with one alphanumeric character? Like `A@#$@#$` or `1@#$@$` but not `#@@#we21!@#` ?

Comment: Fourth textbox   should be 
One number and character should be allowed

Comment: Very good. So in the samples I gave you, the second one will match. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

One number and chars including numbers or excluding numbers?

Using your regex, we can do this to include numbers:

```
^[0-9][0-9a-zA-Z*]+$
```

Or this, to exclude numbers:

```
^[0-9][a-zA-Z*]+$
```

Try it with Regex Hero, but it seems to work.

EDIT: Ok, maybe I did understand that wrong. If you need one letter and one number in any position of the string, you can use this regex:

```
^\w*(?=\w*\d)(?=\w*[a-zA-Z])\w*$
```

(It's a modified version of a regex from [this page](http://nilangshah.wordpress.com/2007/06/26/password-validation-via-regular-expression/), so thanks to the author).